# Dimensional regularization of a divergent integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dimensional-regularization

Suppose there is an integral in four dimension Euclidean space
\begin{equation}
I_{d=4}=\int_0^\infty d^4x\frac{1}{|x|^2},~
\end{equation}
which is divergent. $|x|$ is the length of the vector. Can one use dimensional regularization to compute this integral by using $d^4x \to d^dx$,with $d=4-\epsilon$ ?

Or more abstractly my question is that If I want to compute an integral $I_{d=4}$, but it divergent for example at range $2<d<5$, can we use dimensional regularization by writing $d=4+\epsilon$. Then at the end of calculation let $\epsilon\to0$ ?

Comment: Did you mean the integrals to be over $(-\infty, \infty)$ rather than $(0, \infty)$?

Comment: Yes, actually I meet the following integral in two dimension euclidean plane \begin{equation}\int_c d^2z\frac{1}{(z-z_i)^2(\bar{z}-\bar{z}_i)^2}\end{equation}where $z=x+iy=\rho e^{i \theta}$ and $z_i$ is a constant.  By translation this integral is independent of $z_i$. In polar  coordinate, this integral is just    \begin{equation}  2\pi\int_0^\infty \frac{d\rho}{\rho^3} \end{equation}  My question is can we use dimensional regularization to evaluate this integral.

Comment: This integral doesn't make sense in any number of (integer) dimensions, as $\int d\rho \rho^{-n}$ diverges for any $n$. I therefore can't think of a way to analytically continue to a complex-valued dimension. Why not simply use a momentum-space infrared cutoff $\rho \ge \varepsilon$?

Comment: Since there are some other integral of the form for example \begin{equation}\int d^2z\frac{1}{(z-z_i)(\bar{z}-\bar{z}_j)}\end{equation} which can be computed by dim reg. , so I want to using only one regularization schem in the whole calculation. And I don't know how to compute the latter integral by introducing a cutoff. (The latter integral can be found in 1902.01434)

Comment: Voting -1 for the XY Problem (http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Dim reg: the integral is infinite, but not-log divergent, so therefore the answer is zero!

Answer (score 2):

The method of dimensional regularization in QFT comes with a few definitions which are crucial to evaluating integrals of this type. Following Zinn-Justin, they are the properties of these integrals under the following:

1. Translations:

$$
\int d^d p \, F(p + q) = \int d^d p \, F(p)
$$

2. Dilatations:

$$
\int d^d p \, F(\lambda p) = |\lambda|^{-d} \int d^d p \, F(p)
$$

3. Factorizations:

$$
\int d^d p \, d^{d'}q \, F(p) G(q) = \left( \int d^d p \, F(p) \right) \left( \int  d^{d'}q \, G(q) \right)
$$

From these properties, you can already address some of the integrals you have mentioned. In particular, the first two properties immediately imply the "identity"
$$
\int \frac{d^d p}{(2 \pi)^d} \frac{1}{(p + q)^{2\alpha}} = 0,
$$
for all $d$ and $\alpha$.

In the comments, you have also mentioned the integral
$$
\int_{\mathbb{C}} \frac{d^2 z}{(z - z_i)(\bar{z} - \bar{z}_j)}.
$$
You can consider applying dimensional regularization to this integral, either by introducing multiple copies of $\mathbb{C}$ or writing it as an integral over $\mathbb{R}^2$ and then generalizing to an integration over $\mathbb{R}^d$. You'll find that if $z_j = z_i$, the integral is zero in dimensional regularization, but if $z_j \neq z_i$, I see no reason why it should vanish.

Comment: "the first two properties immediately imply the "identity" $\int \frac{d^d p}{(2 \pi)^d} \frac{1}{(p + q)^{2\alpha}} = 0$ for all $d$ and $\alpha$" : not true for $d=2\alpha$, i.e. logarithmically divergent case.

Comment: That's true - one should also ask that the integrals are holomorphic functions of $d$ with $\alpha$ fixed (and vice-versa), so that divergences take form of poles which may be subtracted. Given that the integral is zero for all $d \neq 2 \alpha$, the only value you can assign to it at $d = 2 \alpha$ consistent with this requirement is also zero.

Answer (score 1):

In dimensional regularisation this integral would normally be set to zero - the reason is that the integrand contains no dimensionful parameter upon which the result can depend. This is curious in qft because it removes ir and uv divergences at the same time

Comment: Actually I want to using dimension regularization to compute  the following 2D integral on complex plane\begin{equation}\int_c d^2z\frac{1}{(z-z_i)^2(\bar{z}-\bar{z}_i)^2}\end{equation} (please see the comments I wrote in above) Is this integral can be set to zero in dimension regularization?